# jquery script to check file size in HTML form before upload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a HTML form which has a jquery script to check file size when SAVE button is pressed.

I have tried my best but the check is not working at all in the HTML Form.

Please help me and Thank in advance. Here is my code

```js
function validate() {
  $("#file_error").html("");
  $(".demoInputBox").css("border-color", "#F0F0F0");
  var file_size = $('#filetoupload')[0].files[0].size;
  if (file_size > 2097152) {
    $("#file_error").html("File size is greater than 2MB");
    $(".demoInputBox").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="submitdesign-add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dname">Upload Your Design </label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" class="demoInputBox" /> <span id="file_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="daddress">Address</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="daddress" name="daddress" type="text" maxlength="95" placeholder="Enter Your Address here" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dcity">City</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="dcity" name="dcity" type="text" maxlength="45" placeholder="Enter Your City here" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Actually your function is not called anywhere, is it?

Comment: how do i do that.. can u guide me on calling this function. cause i did my best possible based on my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things wrong with your code. See the fixed version below.

Here's what changed and made the difference:

1. To make the script be able to select an html-tag you have to put the script in the end of the body. By this the element exists before you try to select it
2. The button needs to be a submit-button, so you have to add `type="submit"`
3. You want to catch the submit-event so you have to add an event-listener `$("#myform").submit(function(event) { ... function body ... });`
4. In this function you can handle the submit event. You call the validate()-function and if it fails, you stop the submit event.
5. If no file was selected the validate function should not be called and the form should not be submitted, so I amended the validate-function to check this.

I also added comments in the code so you can see what changed.

Hope this helps. Though I think you should study some javascript and jQuery, since you were missing many basic points - good luck and have fun coding.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--Srcipt to check file size-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Added an ID to the form to make it selectable even on pages with multiple forms -->
        <form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" action="submitdesign-add.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->

                <!-- File Button --> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dname">Upload Your Design </label>  
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" class="demoInputBox" />
                        <span id="file_error"/>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="daddress">Address</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="daddress" name="daddress" type="text" maxlength="95" placeholder="Enter Your Address here" class="form-control input-md" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dcity">City</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="dcity" name="dcity" type="text" maxlength="45" placeholder="Enter Your City here" class="form-control input-md" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="singlebutton"/>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <!-- Added type="submit" to make the button a submit-button -->
                        <button type="submit" id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
        <script>


        function validate() {
            $("#file_error").html("");
            $(".demoInputBox").css("border-color","#F0F0F0");

            // Test if any file was selected else return false
            if(file_size = $('#filetoupload')[0].files.length == 0) {
                alert("Please select file");
                return false;
            }

            var file_size = $('#filetoupload')[0].files[0].size;
            if(file_size>2097152) {
                $("#file_error").html("File size is greater than 2MB");
                $(".demoInputBox").css("border-color","#FF0000");
                return false;
            } 
            return true;

        }

        /*
         * Bind Event-Listener to submit-button
         */
        $("#myform").submit(function(event) {

            // If validation fails stop sub
            if(validate()) {
                // Stop event of submitting the form
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```